# Complex Inequality on hyperbolic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How can proof $|\sinh(y)|\leq |\sin(z)|\leq |\cosh(y)|$ for every $z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}$, any hinty or auxiliar result.

Comment: this inequality are taken from basic complex analysis of Jerrold Marsden... I'm triying to prove it... but it's $cosh(y)$ I've already correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use
$$\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$
and
$$|e^{iz}|=|e^{ix}e^{-y}|=e^{-y}$$
together with the triangle inequality.

Comment: That's right! one more question... using $sin(z)=sin(x)cosh(y)+sinh(y)cos(x)$ what's the hint?

Comment: I'd try the triangle inequality again, but I think it's easier to use the approach in my answer.

Comment: I know, but my instructor also asks about the using of that definition, in fac't I'd tried to expand and uses identities but I'm not sure to arrived nothing...

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear to me how to use that identity.